# In $\triangle ADC$, angle bisector $DB$ is drawn. If $AB=3$, $AD=6$, and $CD=8$, find $BD$.

Tags: geometry

In my book, the solution starts like this:

$\frac {CB} {AB} = \frac {CD} {AD} = \frac {4} {3}$.

However, I have been taught that the angle bisector theorem (with $\triangle ADC$) is $\frac {AD} {AC} = \frac {DB} {BC}$

It is getting late so I might be missing something, but if I am can someone please explain?

Comment: why are you considering the triangle ABC if ADC is mentioned in the question?

Comment: Sorry I'm tired I meant $\triangle ADC$. I will edit the question. @RamanujanXV

Comment: In that case,what you have been taught is wrong.It should be AB instead of DB in the relation.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem

Comment: Please note you are drawing angle bisector from vertex $D$ and $B \in AC$. Draw a diagram, it should be clear.

Comment: With the angle bisector theorem, you can find $\frac{6}{8}=\frac{3}{BC}$. By simplifying you get $BC=4$. Finally use this solution to find $BD$ https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4388595/946740